# Escaped unicode characters are escaped again with StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml

Tags: java, unicode-escapes, stringescapeutils

I have a text "Begünstigter" which I'm trying to escape the character 'ü' with `StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml`. As the code for 'ü' is `&#252;`, I would expect the method to return `Beg&#252;nstigter`. However, `StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml` is somehow doing the escape until there is no character to escape anymore, meaning after having the value `Beg&#252;nstigter`, it escapes `&` as `&amp;`. That's why the final result I get becomes `Beg&amp;#252;nstigter`. I've tried using commons-text, commons-lang, commons-lang3 with escapeXml10 and escapeXml11 methods as well as some other posted solutions. But nothing seems to work for me. What am I overlooking here, how can I solve this issue?

Here is the full code of where I'm doing this:

```
private void exportRecords(XMLStreamWriter writer, XmlExportDataDescription exportDataDescription) throws XMLStreamException {
        Long companyId = exportDataDescription.getCompanyId();
        String mainTagName = exportDataDescription.getMainTagNameInXml();

        long count = 0;

        Clock clock = Clock.systemDefaultZone();
        writer.writeStartElement(mainTagName);
        while (true) {
            Map<String, Object> parameter = new HashMap<>();
            parameter.put("companyId", companyId);
            parameter.put("offset", count + 1);
            parameter.put("rowNum", count + MANUAL_XML_CREATION_BATCH_SIZE);

            long startTimeResults = clock.millis();
            List<Map<String, Object>> resultList = getSqlMapClientTemplate().queryForList("XML_EXPORT." + mainTagName, parameter);
            long endTimeResults = clock.millis();

            if (resultList.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }

            log.debug("---- Retrieving " + resultList.size() + " results for table " + exportDataDescription.getMainTagNameInXml() + " took " + (endTimeResults - startTimeResults) + " ms");

            count += resultList.size();

            long startTimeBatchWriting = clock.millis();
            for (Map<String, Object> listEntry : resultList) {
                writer.writeStartElement(mainTagName + "_ROW");

                for (Entry<String, Object> entry : listEntry.entrySet()) {
                    if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().equals("rn")) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (entry.getValue() == null) {
                        writer.writeEmptyElement(entry.getKey());
                    } else {
                        writer.writeStartElement(entry.getKey());
                        writer.writeCharacters(StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(entry.getValue().toString()));
                        writer.writeEndElement();
                    }
                }

                writer.writeEndElement();
            }

            long endTimeBatchWriting = clock.millis();
            log.debug("---- Writing batch results for table " + exportDataDescription.getMainTagNameInXml() + " took " + (endTimeBatchWriting - startTimeBatchWriting) + " ms");
        }

        writer.writeEndElement();
        exportDataDescription.setNumberOfDatasets(BigDecimal.valueOf(count));
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - we can't tell whether you're doing something odd like calling `escapeXml` twice.

Comment: @JonSkeet just added my code

Comment: afaik that string doesn't need escaping for xml. If you were to do an html escape on it, you'd get `Beg&uuml;nstigter`

Comment: I think since you are using an XML writer to write the string, you don't need to escape it. But you didn't specify the library you are using. Your code is not an [mcve].

Comment: @RealSkeptic I'm using `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils`. I also need to escape characters <, > in other exported fields. So I cannot simply remove this method.

Comment: That isn't a [mcve]. Ideally, you'd provide us a piece of code we can copy, paste, compile and run to see the problem.

Comment: *I also need to escape characters <, > in other exported fields* Those are `&lt;` and `gt;` If you escape a string with umlauts in it using `StringEscapeUtils`, you'll get the same string back, because they don't need escaping

Comment: Why do you think you need to escape anything before calling the `XMLStreamWriter` `writeCharacters` method? Don't you think the XMLStreamWriter knows how to properly escape XML on its own? Also, what is all this log, Clock, timing, SqlMap blah blah blah code? It doesn't have anything to do with your question. Create a minimal program that just writes the string in question to an XMLStreamWriter plus any escaping. That's a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: Here's a minrep for the API you asked about: `public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {String s = "Begünstigter";if (args.length > 0) {s = args[0];}System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10(s));}` You'll get the same string out again with no arguments. But @DavidConrad is almost certainly right - if the writer doesn't know, unaided, that `<` needs escapement then I'd be very surprised

Comment: @g00se Yes. I just tested it and if the string is `"<Begünstigter>"` it produces a result like `<value>&lt;Begünstigter&gt;</value>`. No prior escaping, just calling `writeCharacters("<Begünstigter>")` directly.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a minimal, reproducible example that show escaping is not necessary before calling `XMLStreamWriter::writeCharacters`:

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter;

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
XMLStreamWriter writer = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamWriter(sw);
writer.writeStartDocument();
writer.writeStartElement("value");
writer.writeCharacters("<Begünstigter>");
writer.writeEndElement();
writer.writeEndDocument();
writer.close();
System.out.println(sw.toString());
```

You can run this on JShell and the output is:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><value>&lt;Begünstigter&gt;</value>"
```

In short, `XMLStreamWriter` already knows how to write XML. You do not need to, and should not, escape text before passing it to the `writeCharacters` method.

Note: some implementations might only escape the `<` (left angle bracket) and not the `>` (right angle bracket); the former is *required* to be encoded while the latter is *optional*, but the result will still be correctly encoded and will be parsed correctly by an XML parser.

Comment: I just tried `writer.writeCharacters` with `<VT><AT><AK><VK><FK>` on my local system and it returns  `&lt;VT>&lt;AT>&lt;AK>&lt;VK>&lt;FK>` .

Comment: @Eda that is correctly escaped.  '<' is _required_ to be escaped in xml but '>' is _optional_.  it looks weird, but any valid xml parser should parse that correctly.

Answer (score -2):

One way to handle it is to unescape the parts that you do not want to escape

```
writer.writeCharacters(
     StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(
       entry.getValue().toString()
     ).replaceAll("&amp;#(\\d+);", "&#$1;")
  );
```

Replacing all the &amp; with &